# Drupal, what's the best way to make a huge form

Tags: forms, drupal

I have to make a huge form in a drupal website, it's for a travel agency and it's a satisfaction questionnaire.
At the beggining of the form the user choose the type of travel he do, and after this all the fields depend of the first answer, for each type of travel there is different fields to complete.

So my question is what's the best way to do this form (there is 12 type of travel, so 12 different set of fields (~50 field / type)).

I think webform could be usable with the webform conditionnal fields, but the problem I think i'll have with webform is when I want to export the data, in the CSV I'll have ALL the fields of ALL the travel type, and this will be illisible.
I search for it but doesn't find if this is possible to hide fields of the csv programmatically.

A second way I found in internet is the CCK, but I have no experience with this.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Maybe you can create a multistep form : https://jamesdavidson.io/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7

Comment: Seems a good solution but it's more easy to create with webform, the only problem I have is for the csv export, with webform I'll have a csv with lines of more than one hundred fields, and I search on the web but doesn't find any solution to modify the csv export function

Comment: the csv export is fired on form submit or it is independant ?

Comment: It's independant, with webform there is a backend where you can export the csv, but I don't find any hook to change the csv export function

Answer (score 0):

you can use hook provided by [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module :

```
/**
 * Alter a Webform submission's data when exported.
 */
function hook_webform_csv_data_alter(&$data, $component, $submission) {
  // If a value of a field was left blank, use the value from another
  // field.
  if ($component['cid'] == 1 && empty($data)) {
    $data = $submission->data[2]['value'][0];
  }
}
```

Found in `webform.api.php` into webform module folder

Also you can modify submit function by own altering form process :

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state , $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'myformid'){
    $form['#submit']= array('mycustomsubmit'); // or loop on existing to suppress only unwanted submit callbacks
  }
} 
function mycustomsubmit($form , &$form_state){
  // do your stuffs csv exports
}
```

Comment: I have a last question, I have to reproduce something like this https://imgur.com/a/I4ftuR7, do you think this is possible with webform ?

Comment: reproduce next / prev navigation ? or multicheckbox? @Jessy

Comment: The table with multi checkbox like in the screen

Comment: You need custom development , i'll try to show you how

Comment: I think i'll do it without webform, the hook csv data alter allows me to custom the data in the csv, but not the csv :/

Comment: @Jessy , try the second solution to replace sumbit who generate csv by yours

Comment: But how can I focus on the csv button submit, and not the form submit ? The csv is generated in back-office when you click on a button, The form['#submit'] is the submit button of the form  :/

Comment: I don't know if you have the answer of that, I'm trying to use `  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')` but I have an error : Error : Class 'Drupal' not found

Comment: @Jessy fork submit function and replace part for export

Comment: Sorry for another question but finally do you know how to do something like in my screen ? I try with suffix and prefix to make a table but doesn't work :/